# Which of the following SSL certificate versions is correct?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am not quite familiar with SSL certificates. I tried to retrieve the SSL certificate version using two different functions. One using the OpenSSL library and one with built-in methods. They return different version numbers for the same domain name. Which one is correct?

This is the code for Python 3.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import OpenSSL
import ssl

def get_ssl_cert1(host, port=443):
    conn = ssl.create_connection((host, port))
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=host)
    certificate = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(sock.getpeercert(True))
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate)
    print("Certificate version from method 1: ", x509.get_version())

def get_ssl_cert2(host, port=443):
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    s = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=host)
    s.connect((host, port))
    cert = s.getpeercert()
    print("Certificate version from method 2: ", cert['version'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = 'www.google.com'
    get_ssl_cert1(host)
    get_ssl_cert2(host)
```

Result:

```
Certificate version from method 1:  2
Certificate version from method 2:  3
```

I expected the results to be the same.

Comment: Perhaps one of them is returning the numeric value of the version field (2) and the other is producing the "logical version" (3)?  (0 is v1, 1 is v2, 2 is v3)

Comment: Yes, this was the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Method 2 shows actual x509 version, while method 1 shows zero based x509 version, where 0=v1, 1=v2, 2=v3.. So in practice, they both show that version 3 is used. You can try this yourself using `openssl x509 -text -in YOURCERT.pem`
, and you will get something like

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
```

and you can see, that the version 3 is given, but also in parenthesis a hex value (2) which is based on the zero-based versioning. It's just a matter of which of your libraries use which method